# Get Section Handle From Group

Tags: entries, sections, group

I have a landing page on my site where I want to list a group of sections that have entries. I also need to access the section handle of that same group of sections.

I am having problems getting the section handle for the sections.

Currently I get an error back that says impossible to access attribute ("handle") on a string variable.

```
        {% set specialEntries = craft.entries.section(['sec1','sec2','sec3']) %}

        {% set grouped = specialEntries|group('section') %}
        {% for section, specialEntries in grouped %}
            <h1>{{ section }} - {{ section.handle }}</h1>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you're attempting to use a `SectionModel` instance as the key for your grouped entries. This is not possible.

What actually happens behind the scenes is the `group` filter generates an object where the keys are the string value of the `SectionModel` instance [1], and the values are the `EntryModels` associated with that section.

There are a few ways of achieving your desired outcome. Here's one possibility (not tested):

```
{% set sections = craft.sections.getAllSections() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(['first', 'second', 'third']) %}
{% set grouped = entries|group('section') %}

{% for sectionHandle, sectionEntries in grouped %}
    {% set groupSection = false %}
    {% for section in sections %}
        {% if section.name == sectionHandle %}
            {% set groupSection = section %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if groupSection %}
        <h1>{{ groupSection.name }} - {{ groupSection.handle }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

[1]: The [`SectionModel::__toString` method](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/SectionModel#__toString-detail) returns the `name` attribute.

Comment: Glad I could help 

Comment: Now that I have the sections outputting, I need to sort them.  Ideally by structureId.  I've tried applying supersort to the "grouped" query but I'm not getting the results I would expect.  Any advice?

Comment: You should probably post a separate question for that.